# Different number of parameters in FORM and PERFORM

Tags: abap

I want to avoid copy+paste in my function and want to create a subroutine.

But this fails.

Here is the function (I removed unimportant parts):

```
FUNCTION /foo/bar .
*"----------------------------------------------------------------------
*"  IMPORTING
*"     VALUE(IV_STATIC_PARAMETER_LIST) TYPE  WDY_KEY_VALUE_LIST
*"----------------------------------------------------------------------

data selection_table TYPE TABLE OF RSPARAMS.

PERFORM GET_REPORT_READ_PARAMETER
    USING IV_DYNAMIC_PARAMETER_LIST
   CHANGING selection_table.
```

I get this error message:

> Different number of parameters in FORM and PERFORM (routine:
>   GET_REPORT_READ_PARAMETER, number of formal parameters: 4, number of
>   actual parameters: 2)

The subroutine looks like this:

```
FORM GET_REPORT_READ_PARAMETER
  USING parameter_list TYPE  WDY_KEY_VALUE_LIST
  CHANGING sel_table TYPE TABLE OF RSPARAMS.

....

ENDFORM
```

Any idea why ABAP thinks that there are 4 and not 2 parameters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is in this line:

```
CHANGING sel_table TYPE TABLE OF RSPARAMS
```

By typing the parameter the above syntax is not valid, "`OF`" and "`RSPARAMS`" are interpreted as separate `CHANGING` parameters.
You have to type the parameter directly with a table type (like you do for the `USING` parameter). In this case it can be:

```
CHANGING sel_table TYPE RSPARAMS_TT.
```

RSPARAMS_TT is table type of RSPARAMS (you can check in SE11)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would this work (without RSPARAMS_TT), if I would create a "real" function and not just a subroutine with "FORM ... ENDFORM"?

Comment: @guettli No, you can't use so-called "bound data types" for the parameters of all types of procedures, whatever they are subroutines, function modules and methods (bound data types are built with `DATA`, `STATICS`, `CLASS-DATA`). You may define the types you want with `TYPES` (so-called "standalone data types") and then you use them to type the parameters. The other way to type parameters without defining standalone data types is to use generic types, as you did with `sel_table type TABLE` (other generic types are C, N, P, X, any, numeric, simple, any table, index table, etc.)

Comment: @SandraRossi are there canonical docs from upstream (sap) which explain "bound data types". I can find several blog posts and books about this, but I would like to have canonical docs from the makers of the language. (That's something where Python and the Django Web Framework are great).

Comment: @guettli If you want to become skillful in ABAP terminology, read the difficult but very precise official ABAP documentation : [Bound and Standalone Data Types](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/index.htm?file=abenbound_independent_dtype_guidl.htm) ; terminologies are in section "ABAP Glossary". Example to avoid pain: a "bound data type" is the type of the constant FRANCE declared with `CONSTANTS france TYPE c LENGTH 3 VALUE 'FRA'.` Instead of a bound type, you may use a standalone type `TYPES country_iso TYPE c LENGTH 3. DATA france TYPE country_iso VALUE 'FRA'.`

Comment: @SandraRossi the official ABAP docs helped me. Thank you. I am beginning to see the light.

Comment: @SandraRossi is there a way to create an issue at sap? It would be very helpful to have a better error message here (in the future). A team mate and I wasted some time because we had no clue why ABAP thinks we need to pass 4 parameters. It would be nice if ABAP could tell me: "please read the docs about bound vs standalone data types".

Comment: @guettli To create an issue, use https://support.sap.com but you need a client S-user (S followed by 10 numeric digits). In your particular case, you won't get a favorable answer because SAP don't invest on obsolete technologies (i.e. subroutines). And with the 7.40 and 7.5x versions, the syntax messages are even worse in many domains, especially the constructor expressions.