# Different parameter count in FORM and PERFORM

Tags: abap, subroutine

I am trying to add a formal parameter in the FORM and PERFORM in an existing code, as I will be need it the extra parameter in a new function that I have to call. The idea is that when executing the new code it keeps showing the error: **Different parameter count in FORM and PERFORM (routine: CM_SHOW_CRC, number of formal parameters: 2, number of actual parameters: 3).**

The code that I have for the form part is as follows:

```
FORM cm_show_crc
  USING
    civ_matnr TYPE matnr                  
    civ_charg TYPE charg_d                
    civ_werks TYPE werks_d.          "The parameter that I added
```

And the perform code is:

```
 PERFORM cm_show_crc
        USING
          pis_sdow_alv-matnr
          pis_sdow_alv-charg
          pis_sdow_alv-werks.        "The parameter that I added
```

The table **pis_sdow_alv** is type of a structure that also includes the variable **WERK(Component type WERKS_D)**

Before adding the new parameter **WERK** the code was working fine.

May anyone know what the problem in this part of the code may be?

There was also another similar question in: [Different number of parameters in FORM and PERFORM](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53101871/16094547), however I am not using the syntax **CHANGING** in my code, as it was also not used prior.

Please do tell me if you need additional information.

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: The other question would also apply to `USING`, but your question is different. I think that your issue is that the 2 parts of the code are defined in two different program includes, and you don't activate both at the same time. Save both. Then press Ctrl+F3, SAP should propose both, select both and activate.

Comment: @SandraRossi Many thanks, activating them both solved the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem can occur when `FORM` and `PERFORM` are in different includes and you only activate one but not the other.

When you activate an include, then it is checked against the *active* version of all other repository objects it depends on. Not the *saved* version. This can lead to an annoying catch-22 situation. You can not activate A because it does not match the previous version of B, and you can not activate B because it does not match the previous version of A.

The solution to this conundrum is to activate both objects together. When you activate something in SE80 and you have multiple inactive objects, you get a window where you can select multiple objects to activate together:

[image: activate multiple SAPGui]

In Eclipse, you get a similar list by clicking on the "activate multiple" button:
[image: activate multiple Eclipse]